# failed test " Expected spy doDeleteRule to have been called.", jasmine, karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

A straight forward test is failing, using jasmine. 
"Expected spy doDeleteRule to have been called."
I noticed that if I remove the if statement within the subscribe clause, it passes. However the if statement is required, as I only want the method to execute when the returned observable value equals true. Is there extra I need to do/check?

Spec:

```
it('Should confirm delete before deletion, confirmDeleteRule', async(() => {
    const spyDoDeleteRule = spyOn(component, 'doDeleteRule');
    const spyShowConfirmModal = spyOn(confirmService, 'showConfirmModal').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));
    component.confirmDeleteRule(new Event('click'), 5);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(spyShowConfirmModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spyDoDeleteRule).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

component:

```
  public confirmDeleteRule(ev: Event, rowIndex: number) {
    const modalConfig: ConfirmModalConfig = new ConfirmModalConfig(
      this.translateService.instant('overlay_group_modal_rule_delete.title'),
      this.translateService.instant('overlay_group_modal_rule_delete.rule_name') + ' ' + this.allRules[rowIndex] +
      this.translateService.instant('overlay_group_modal_rule_delete.prompt'),
      [
        [this.translateService.instant('actions.ok'), ConfirmButtonActions.YES],
        [this.translateService.instant('actions.cancel'), ConfirmButtonActions.CANCEL],
      ],
      ConfirmIcons.WARN,
    );

    this.confirmService.showConfirmModal(modalConfig, true).pipe(
      mergeMap((action: ConfirmButtonActions) => {
        if (action === ConfirmButtonActions.YES) {
          return Observable.of(true);
        } else {
          return Observable.of(false);
        }
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        throw Observable.of(err);
      }),
    ).subscribe((deleteRule: boolean) => {
      if (deleteRule) {
        this.doDeleteRule(ev, rowIndex);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `confirmDeleteRule` contains asynchronous code. Placing `await` in front of the line that invokes this method, should solve the problem (see [async/await](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async#asyncawait)).

```
await component.confirmDeleteRule(new Event('click'), 5);
```